# Function returns [object Set] instead of an actual Set

Tags: javascript, function, object, set

I have a function

```
function recursiveDivisionWrap(width, height, colStart, colEnd, rowStart, rowEnd)
```

in which i have an empty set

```
let blockedNodes = new Set();
```

inside this function I have another, recursive function

```
function recursiveDivision(width, height, colStart, colEnd, rowStart, rowEnd)
```

On each call of the **recursiveDivision** function i update a ***blockedNodes*** set by adding value:

```
for (let i = colStart; i < colEnd; i++) {
        blockedNodes.add(`c${i}r${wallStart}`);
      }
```

If I console.log ***blockedNodes*** set inside **recursiveDivision** function, I'm getting desired result, for example:

```
Set(43) {'c0r7', 'c1r7', 'c2r7', 'c3r7', 'c4r7', …}
```

However when I console.log ***blockedNodes*** set inside **recursiveDivisionWrap** and not in recursiveDivision, I'll get comma separated object:

```
c0r7,c1r7,c2r7,c3r7,c4r7,c5r7,c6r7,c7r7,c8r7,c9r7,c9r0,c9r1,c9r2,c9r3,c9r4,c9r5,c9r6,c8r0,c8r1,c8r2,c8r3,c8r4,c8r5,c8r6,c3r0,c3r1,c3r2,c3r3,c3r4,c3r5,c3r6,c4r6,c5r6,c6r6,c7r6,c4r1,c5r1,c6r1,c7r1,c4r5,c5r5,c6r5,c7r5
```

I've also tried with array and the result was the same.

Why doesn't it return `Set(43) {'c0r7', 'c1r7', 'c2r7', 'c3r7', 'c4r7', …}` if the ***blockedNodes*** set is defined outside the **recursiveDivision** function and inside **recursiveDivisionWrap** and why does the inner **recursiveDivision** function returns correct set?
I would appreciate any help in finding answer to that question.

Comment: Please provide the code in one piece, which, when we execute it, illustrates the problem.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/kubakosmal/e5be2d126b289683a0c0b292d29d7407

Comment: Just include that in your question. There is a toolbar button to create a runnable snippet. But be sure to provide the *minimal* code necessary to reproduce the problem. Remove anything that is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour has nothing to do with the *place* where the output is made, but how the output is formatted.

You have these statements:

```
console.log(blockedNodes);
```

And:

```
console.log(`Is this a set? ${blockedNodes}`);
```

And:

```
let ecie = Array.from(blockedNodes);
console.log(`Is this an array? ${ecie}`)
```

They don't do the same thing.

`console.log(blockedNodes)` leaves the rendering to the `console` API, which may provide additional information, like the name of the constructor of the object (`Set` in this case), the number of items this collection has, ...etc. It may even add user-interface controls to expand/collapse the contents of the collection and potential nested data structures.

`` console.log(`Is this a set? ${blockedNodes}`) `` will implicitly call `blockedNodes.toString()` in order to produce the string. Unless `toString` has been overriden, that will render as `[object Set]`, and so the total output will be "Is this a set? [object Set]".

`` console.log(`Is this an array? ${ecie}`) `` will also call the `toString` method, but this time on `ecie`, which is an array (as that is what `Array.from` returned). The `toString` method on arrays produces a comma separated list of the values, which explains the output you mentioned.

Comment: You explained this perfectly. Thank You!